# how to set the Nginx basic auth ineffective in browser manually

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, nginx, browser

## description

here is my problem :
I've used to add basic auth in my docker container successfully ,and I open my website page ,and input the basic auth's name and password correctly,so the next time when I open my site ,for a long time I don't need to reinput them again .that's cool ,cause I konw the browser will remember sth for me.
now i removed the basic auth in my Nginx configure  file ,and restart the server ,and I want to check if the change effects ,but when I open my site this time ,still no need to input name and password , but I am not sure if it's the configure change effects well or the browser has already remember the authorization for ,so I want to remove or delete the already exist authorization in my browser .
of course I can find other device that has never been sign in before to check ,but I am curious  about how the browser remember or store the name and password or authorization that has already been inputed,and if I can delete this things manually .

Comment: Most browsers would keep basic auth login/password until you restart them completely (I mean browser, not the server). This means you should close **all** opened tabs and windows.

Comment: @IvanShatsky thx for ur help ,i guess i just need to restart the browser

Comment: @IvanShatsky would be great if you could add your comment as an answer so I can vote it.
Your comment rescued me after wracking my brain for hours trying to debug why disabling basic auth is not working on my nginx.